# Service Provider that requires elevation

Tags: multi-factor, identity-management

Our identities are stored in a separate IdP (Azure AD in this case) and the applications are acting as Service Providers. MFA is triggered based on some rules (based on geoIP etc.). We are now about to add a new application which contain sensitive data and wish for it to trigger MFA.

What are the mechanism for Service Providers to request Elevation?

For example, is there an attribute that should be passed through the OIDC/SAML to indicate if it's MFAed? Is there a protocol by which the Service Provider requests that elevation so that the IdP knows to trigger it? Is it widely implemented by IAM products and specifically in Azure AD?

Answer (score 3):

The mechanism depends on the protocol but in practice MFA at the protocol level is not standardized. For example in SAML, you can make use of an [authentication context](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-authn-context-2.0-os.pdf):

> If a relying party is to rely on the authentication of another entity
>   by an authentication authority, the relying party may require
>   information additional to the authentication itself to allow it to put
>   the authentication into a risk-management context. This information
>   could include:
>
> - The initial user identification mechanisms (for
>     example, face-to-face, online, shared secret).
> - The mechanisms for 
>     minimizing compromise of credentials (for example, credential renewal
>     frequency, client-side key generation).
> - The mechanisms for storing
>     and protecting credentials (for example, smartcard, password rules).
> - The authentication mechanism or method (for example, password,
>     certificate-based SSL)

The relying party could ask the identity provider to use MFA when authenticating the user If MFA is not used, the relying party could reject SAML assertion and therefore deny access. Sounds good, doesn't it? This is theory. In practice, this doesn't work at the protocol level because defining the behavior of a specific authentication context is not something that can be universally specified.

SAML as a protocol allows extensions so any party could publish their own authentication context. As long as that context is understood by SPs and IdPs that participate in a federation, it all works. Not quite universal but it's a solution. In a higher education community where SAML via Shibboleth is widespread, they've defined a [profile](https://refeds.org/profile/mfa) for MFA along with associated authentication context and baked it into implementations.

OIDC also has authentication contexts and they suffer from the same problem as described above. Since OIDC is built on top of oAuth, it also has scopes as another control lever to request desired access. If there was, say, a standard 'mfa' scope  then the client could request it from the authorization service. Alas, only a few scopes are standardized.

When you're dealing with a large, commercial identity provider such as Azure AD, your ability to implement to your needs is subject to

1. Specifications they support
2. Their interpretation of these specifications
3. Your ability to customize their behavior and still remain within the spec.

While AAD supports SAML and OIDC, it does so narrowly and you can customize very little. To be specific, you can't ask AAD to interpret your own scopes or authentication contexts.

Since you know upfront that this particular app is going to need MFA, your best implementation option in AAD is a [conditional access policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/app-based-mfa).